# What is the difference between firebase database transaction with and without async-await?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have seen code which used firebase database transaction which is done in typeScript using async-await. But also I have seen doing this in javascript without using async-await. What is the difference between these two? Is there any performance related issue?

Answer (score 1):

No async await is just a neat way of handling promises. The firebase transactions returns a promise, which is resolved only when transaction completes/fails/stop. As you can see the transaction have a callback as parameter which is called as the transaction updates.

There is no performance difference, its just a different syntax and clean way to handle promises.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data#section-transactions

Comment: Does that mean I can write code without using async-await for concurrent data modification in Firebase?

Comment: Yes. The [example in the Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions) doesn't use `async`/`await` and works without problems. If you're having problem getting transactions to work, post a question with a [minimal, complete, verifiable example that reproduces where you got stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).